# Separating concerns in asp.net-core EF project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, repository, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm attempting to refactor my project into different layers. I currently have all my business logic and data access going on in my MVC controller, which seems hard to maintain in the future.

I am using Microsoft Identity too, and have tried to implement the repository and unit of work pattern by passing my context as a parameter:

```
public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _db = context;
}

public void Complete()
{
    _db.SaveChanges();
}

public CustomerRepository CustomerRepository => _customerRepository ?? customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(_db));

//dispose methods
```

And my repository:

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public CustomerRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer(string id)
    {
        return _db.Customers
            .Include(c => c.User)
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ApplicationUserId == id);
    }
}
```

I want my MVC controllers to access my repositories through a business logic layer. I can access entities just fine through my repository but how can I update entities or perform business logic on them?

I've tried to implement a logic layer like this:

```
public class CustomerLogic
{ 
    private readonly UnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public CustomerLogic(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context);
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer(string id)
    {
        return unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetCustomer(id);
    }
    public void UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
       unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.UpdateCustomer(customer);        
       unitOfWork.Complete();
    }
}
```

I'm not able to update my customer entity and I think it is caused by passing my dbcontext around like a parameter but I see no other solution. Is my architectural approach wrong or is it simply too advanced to separate concerns in an ef core application with microsoft identity for someone who is not an expert?

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault` in `GetCustomer` method.

Comment: First, *don't* implement the repository/UoW patterns. An ORM like EF already implements these patterns, so it's redundant and adds unnecessary entropy to your code. If you want to abstract the data layer, use something like the service layer or CQRS patterns.